# Product viewed on Opencart product.tpl

Tags: product, opencart, viewer

How to add product_viewed on opencart product page to calculate the product views?

Here is an image:

[Image http://imglink.ru/pictures/20-06-12/094b53c8a98506e2c13f499289f8cec0.jpg](http://imglink.ru/pictures/20-06-12/094b53c8a98506e2c13f499289f8cec0.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just be able to add

```
<?php echo $product_info['viewed']; ?>
```

to your template (product.tpl)